# Sharepoint 2016 on-premise details Item Version field informations

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I am working on SharePoint 2016 CSOM to get list item version history. unfortunately i am not getting the field values. please find the code below.

```
       var file = item.File;
            var versionFiles = file.Versions;
            var fa = file.ListItemAllFields;

            clientContext.Load(fa);
            clientContext.Load(file);
            clientContext.Load(versionFiles);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            if (null != versionFiles)
            {
                var fileVersion = file.Versions[5];
                SP.File oldFile =web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/site/_vti_history/1234/list1/file1.pdf");
                var allField = oldFile.ListItemAllFields;
                clientContext.Load(allField);


             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get version history metadata from Lists.asmx.

Sample code:

```
var web = clientContext.Web;
                List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDoc");                
                var item = spList.GetItemById(43);
                clientContext.Load(spList);
                clientContext.Load(item);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                #region customList
                Lists.Lists listService = new Lists.Lists();
                listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                listService.Url = siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
                XmlNode nodeAttachments = listService.GetVersionCollection(spList.Id.ToString(), item.Id.ToString(), "Title");

                foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xNode in nodeAttachments)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xNode.Attributes["Title"].Value);
                }
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it gives all fields or specified filed in version history

Comment: Just for specific field, need call listService.GetVersionCollection(spList.Id.ToString(), item.Id.ToString(), "FieldName"); to get other fields.

Comment: Thank you.can we call "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" using http client in c#

Comment: Reference the service as webservice will be simple. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-web-services/. You have to construct the soap if you call web service by httprequest https://forums.asp.net/t/1799042.aspx?How+to+call+WebMethod+of+a+Web+service+using+HttpWebRequest+object+

Comment: i am trying consume the share point web service in .net core. do you have any idea how to add  web reference